# Add legend to Dash DataTable

Tags: python, legend, plotly-dash, tabular

Starting from the following code, I'd like to add a legend to this tabular:

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

See also: https://dash.plotly.com/datatable

I'd like to have something like this on the bottom of the screen:

| Column | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| State | The state for which the data was collected. |
| Number of Solar Plants | The total number of solar plants in the state. |
| Installed Capacity (MW) | The installed capacity in megawatts. |
| Average MW Per Plant | The average power production in megawatts. |
| Generation (GWh) | Generated gigawatts per hour. |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the table is displayed close together and at full display width, you can use inine-block to insert spaces and optimize column widths.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dash_table
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import pandas as pd

explain = ["The state for which the data was collected.",
           "The total number of solar plants in the state.",
           "The installed capacity in megawatts.",
           "The average power production in megawatts.",
           "Generated gigawatts per hour."]     

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')
df_legend = pd.DataFrame({'Column':df.columns, 'Explanation': explain})

#app = Dash(__name__)
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='div1', children=[
        dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns])
    ]),
    html.Div(id='div2', children=[
        dash_table.DataTable(
        data=df_legend.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_legend.columns],
        )
    ], style={'display': 'inline-block'})
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)#, mode='inline'
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very nice solution. Thank you very much! Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. I simply added a second tabular as a legend.

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from dash import html

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/solar.csv')

app = Dash(__name__)

explanations = ["The state for which the data was collected.", "The total number of solar plants in the state.", "The installed capacity in megawatts.", "The average power production in megawatts.", "Generated gigawatts per hour."]

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'),
                         [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns]),
    dash_table.DataTable([{"Column": "State", "Explanation": "The state for which the data was collected."},
                          {"Column": "Number of Solar Plants", "Explanation": "The total number of solar plants in the state."},
                          {"Column": "Installed Capacity (MW)", "Explanation": "The installed capacity in megawatts."},
                          {"Column": "Average MW Per Plant", "Explanation": "The average power production in megawatts."},
                          {"Column": "Generation (GWh)", "Explanation": "Generated gigawatts per hour."},],
                           [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in ["Column", "Explanation"]]),
    html.Div(id='datatable-interactivity-container')
])

#app.layout = 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```